# C++: Using the same function layout with different operators and class methods

Tags: c++, function, templates, member

I have a function layout like the following one:

```
bool foo( object1, object2, method_x, op_y, method_z ) {
    if (object1.method_x() op_y object2.method_z()) {
        do something;
}
```

The objects object1 and object2 are always from the same class. But their methods and the operators in between are arbitrary. I know you can pass an operator as a template parameter and this would do the job. But what about the member functions? They take no arguments if that helps.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I sense an XY problem here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I just want to avoid writing the same function layout over and over again with some little changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to avoid typing, MACROs are the usual (evil) mechanism here.

In C++1y you could use polymorphic lambdas to achieve something similar.

```
foo(object1, object2, 
      [](auto o) { return o.method_x(); }, 
      [](auto a, auto b) { return a == b }, 
      [](auto o) { return o.method_z() });
```

Of course as long as the methods are just that, you could

```
foo(object1, object2, 
      std::memfn(&Object1::method_x),
      [](auto a, auto b) { return a == b }, 
      std::memfn(&Object2::method_z));
```

Update: since you added that types can be restricted, you could replace all the `auto` with the appropriate type and maybe use

```
template <typename T, typename Mx, typename Op, typename Mz>
bool foo(T& object1, T& object2, Mx method_x, Op op_y, Mz method_z ) {
    if (op_y(method_x(object1), method_z(object2)) {
        // do something;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why one wouldn't use a macro here.. Not all compilers support lambdas (mine does not), and until nearly all do, I would suggest sticking with the plain types and methods.

Comment: Thank you! I can't use C++11 in my project but I'll definitely try your first solution somewhere else :D.

Comment: @phyrrus9 you don't need lambdas. You can even use `std::less<T>`, `std::greater_equal<T>` etc.